# ошибка zic компилятора

Tags: linux, время

Работаю на Slackware 10.0.0, Linux 2.4.26,
потребовалось обновить файлы часовых зон, при компиляции возникает ошибка:

```
/usr/sbin/zic asia
"asia", line 1843: invalid time of day
```

UPD:
Выяснил, что есть пакет tzdata распространяется вместе с пакетом tzcode, содержащий zic компилятор.

Можно ли считать что скомпилированные файлы tzdata с часовыми поясами платформ-независимые, то есть можно ли их просто скопировать с одного компьютера на другой?

Comment: если опустить стандартную подколку по поводу криокамеры, то как именно пытаешься обновить? `zic` — это часть пакета `tzcode`, он выпускается одной версией с `tzdata`, так что скорей всего полноценно формат `tzdata` поддерживается, по меньшей мере не более старыми версиями (а возможно даже только точно такой же версией) `tzcode`, что и `tzdata`, которую пытаешься собрать...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Я думал что zic-это часть пакета glibc, а tzdata - прокто текстовые исходники с описанием часовых зон. А сейчас внимательнее посмотрел в репозитории IANA, действительно есть пакет tzcode, после установки компилируется без ошибок.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zic` — это часть пакета `tzcode`, он выпускается одним релизом с `tzdata`. Формат — `tzdata` простой текстовый файл, но со временем в него могут вноситься изменения, а также в `tzcode` исправляют ошибки не проявлявшиеся на старых версиях tzdata. Таким образом, вообще говоря, для сборки `tzdata` нужна не меньшая версия `tzcode` (а возможно даже только точно такая же).